# How do you generate a access token to retrieve Facebook Ads report stats?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve the ads report stats, outlined here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats/

But I am currently stuck with generating an access token. I was going through here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview/ ,

And it looks like the only way to generate an access token is to generate it by using live web app.

Is there any other way to generate an access token?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the only way to get a User access token is to have a user authorise your app via the documented login methods: full documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/

Answer (score 0):

No.

At least not as far as I can tell. It appears that you need 3 things to generate the token: 
App Id, App Secret, Url

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview/

in the Provide Authorization section.

---

I'm having a similar issue.

You don't want a client token, you need to generate an access token for the ads reporting.

I've found the Facebook API somewhat confusing because they seem to blur the lines of Access Tokens for accessing user information, and Access Tokens for accessing reporting information.